# why is the output running indefinitely and not producing the end result? (High-low game)

Tags: python, binary-search

I am writing code for a higher/lower guessing game. Basically we have a integer n, and a guess, and 0<guess<n, and I am using binary search to arrive at the guess. Here is my code:

```
n = 75
guess = 70
if guess == n:
   print(guess)

   left = 0
   right = n

   while left <= right:
       mid = left + right //2

        if guess > mid:
            left = mid
            print(left)

        elif guess < mid:
            right = mid
            print(right)

        else:
            print(mid)
            break

if left > right:
    print("Cannot be correct")
```

For some reason my output is just producing 38,74,74,74,74,74.... and is stuck on 74- any idea why this is?
I have deliberately written print within the 'while' function, and it seems that the code is being such on one of the 'elif's'

Comment: The code you provided does not produce the output you mention - please provide the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: also, next time print meaningful prints... for example (print(f'1 mid is: {mid}'))

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that, in `left + right // 2`, the `//` operator has precedence over `+`. It should be `(left + right) // 2`.  Here is the fixed code (with correct indentation and the forgotten `else:`):

```
n = 75
guess = 70
if guess == n:
    print(guess)
else:
    left = 0
    right = n

    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2

        if guess > mid:
            left = mid
            print(f'a. left={left} mid={mid} right={right}')

        elif guess < mid:
            right = mid
            print(f'b. left={left} mid={mid} right={right}')

        else:
            print(f'c. left={left} mid={mid} right={right}')
            break
```

Comment: ahhh okay! Thank you!